# Using `this->` in a lambda that captures `this`

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

There are several similar questions out there, but I can't find a definitive answer to this specific point.

Is it completely equivalent to use or not use `this->` when calling a method or a member variable within a lambda that captures `this`, or there is some nuanced difference?

```
class C {

    int var;
    void foo();

    void fool() {

       auto myLambda = [this] () {
           //
           this->var = 1;
           this->foo();
           // 100% equivalent to?
           var = 1;
           foo();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What else could it be - there is no name `var` declared inside the lambda body or captured otherwise.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess I am still a bit confused about the meaning of capturing `this`. Is it correct to say that the `[this]` capture imports the class `C` namespace inside the lambda, as opposed to just capturing the value of the  `this` pointer?

Comment: @KerrekSB coming from python & ML communities I am routinely surprised by the condenscending tone around basic C++ questions. To reply to your "question": it could be many things if C++ acted slightly differently. For example this could have hypothetically been not allowed in some obscure circumstances, there could have been some arcane security violation involved because of how lambda functions are stored in memory, who knows? OP posted a legitimate and understandable question driven by the desire to write code that he fully understands

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Default-capturing `[this]` both captures the instance pointer and means that name searching within the lambda also includes the class namespace. So, if a matching variable name is found, it refers to that variable in the captured instance (unless shadowed in a closer scope, etc.).

So, yes, using `var` in this context is equivalent to/shorthand for `this->var`. Exactly the same as using a member name within a regular instance function!

Comment: Got it. My confusion was probably due to the fact that `this` is not  variable but a keyword.

Comment: Dunno if this is good enough for the answer, so I'll put it here and gauge response. If it helps: You can think of capturing `this` as making the lambda an 'honorary' member function, where capture is equivalent to the hidden `this` passed to real member functions, with the same results, except always on the captured instance.  Invoking the lambda is then conceptually the same as calling `capturedThis->honoraryMethod(params)`. Another analogy might be to the common need for a class `static` callback function with a 'user data' pointer specifying the instance, albeit with implicit dereferencing

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ';' after declaration lambda.

```
this->var = 1;
this->foo();
// 100% equivalent to?
var = 1;
foo();
```

Yes it's equivalent.

Comment: @Gar: Declarations must end in a semicolon: `int n = 10;`. Your declaration of `myLambda` is missing that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Gar isn't the OP. As the OP didn't mention a compilation error and thus the semicolon was probably a transcription typo, my guess is they were requesting elaboration on _why_ it's equivalent. As is, this answer focusses on a typo and provides no explanation for the part that addresses the real question. In such a case, it's valid to ask for more.